# Accord du nom de famille

Tags: pluriel, accord, noms-propres, noms-de-famille

Quand j'ai besoin de parler d'une famille je généralise souvent par leur nom de famille de cette façon :

> As-tu vu les Duponts récemment ?

J'ai cru comprendre dans mes recherches que les noms propres sont toujours invariables mais qu'il y a des exceptions. **Est-ce qu'il est acceptable d'accorder le nom de famille dans ce cas ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En règle générale, les prénoms et noms de famille sont invariables. On peut penser par exemple à la série américaine *Les Simpson*. Il y a cependant quelques exceptions pour les noms de certaines familles illustres, les sujets représentés et les noms employés métaphoriquement.

Ma copie du logiciel [Antidote HD](https://www.druide.com/a_description.html) (version 6.1) offre les règles suivantes au sujet de la pluralisation des noms propres de personnes :

> ### Sont invariables
>
> Les prénoms :
>   *Il y a trois **Stéphanie** dans ma classe.*
>
> Les noms de famille :
>   *Nous allons chez les **Duval**.
>
>   Les **Bonaparte**, les **Habsbourg**, les **Romanov**.
>
>   Les frères **Kennedy**, les sœurs **Brontë**.
>
>   Les deux **Corneille** (Pierre et Thomas) ont écrit des tragédies.*
>
> Les noms employés avec le pluriel emphatique :
>   *Le siècle des **Voltaire** et des **Rousseau**.*
>
> Les œuvres d’artistes :
>   *Admirer des **Cézanne**, des **Picasso**, deux **Van Gogh**.*
>
> Les titres d’œuvres, de livres :
>   *J’ai deux **Hamlet** dans ma bibliothèque.*
>
> Les noms de fabricants, de marques :
>   *Des **Ford**, des **Renault**, deux **Ferrari**.*
>
> ### Prennent la marque du pluriel
>
> Les noms de sujets représentés :
>   *Des **Cupidons** et deux **Aphrodites** en marbre.*
>
> Les noms employés métaphoriquement :
>   *Ces enfants sont de véritables petits **Mozarts**.
>
>   Ils se prennent pour des **Einsteins**.*
>
> Les noms (français ou francisés) des familles illustres suivantes :
>   *Les **Antonins**, les **Bourbons**, les **Césars**, les **Constantins**, les **Curiaces**, les **Flaviens**, les **Gracques**, les **Horaces**, les **Mac(c)abées**, les **Paléologues**, les **Plantagenêts**, les **Ptolémées**, les **Sévères**, les **Tarquins**, les **Tudors**.*
>
> Facultativement :
>   *Les **Capet(s)**, les **Capulet(s)**, les **Condé(s)**, les **Guise(s)**, les **Montaigu(s)**, les **Montmorency(s)**, les **Scipion(s)**, les **Stuart(s)**.*

Comment: Cette réponse recoupe ce qui est dit dans le Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale.

Comment: Excellent. Voir aussi, _LBU_ §523 et [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3920), similaires.

Answer (score 2):

C'est généralement une règle assez efficace de ne jamais pluraliser les noms propres de personnes (prénoms ou noms de famille). En théorie, un certains nombres de noms anciens et illustres la prennent (cf. la réponse de jlliagre), mais je ne suis pas certain que toutes les grammaires s'entendent sur les cas où cela s’applique!

Si ces noms sont employés pour désigner autre choses (par exemple des archétypes ou des objets désignés du nom de leur fabricant), il peut y avoir variabilité, mais l'usage (Grevisse, bon usage, §525) ne semble pas très bien défini.

Answer (score 1):

Seuls quelques patronymes illustres peuvent **optionnellement** prendre la marque du pluriel comme les Bourbons et les Tudors.