# What does "les" + Singular Proper Noun mean?

Tags: articles, noms-propres

What does

> "les" + singular proper noun

signify?

For example, what does

> les Jean

mean? "Johns"? In the sense of: "People like Jean"?

Comment: Could you provide more context ? As a native French speaking I don't think I've ever seen this kind of construction. Are you sure it was not "Les gens" which sounds the same ?

Comment: @TimF Here's the French sentence I read: "_Ils nous présentent des théories mécaniques singulièrement déchues du degré où les avaient portées les Jean Buridan et les Albert de Saxe._"

Comment: OK, so here I think it means "the people similar as Jean Buridan or Albert de Saxe". It's representing a category of people by naming two of them.

Comment: @TimF That's exactly what I thought, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes you can find this kind of construction. For instance, "Les Baptiste" will mean "All people named Baptiste". The proper noun can also refer to a entire familly like "les Dupond" (without additional "s").

Answer (score 3):

In French, family names don't take an s in the plural, so I'd guess that this refers to "the Jean family." Some additional context would help, though. :)

Comment: There is the same in English: the Simpsons for example.

Comment: Except that in English, we add an "s" when referring to more than one person named "Simpson." I remember seeing "Les Simpson" on a DVD case in France and being surprised by it—that's actually how I first learned this "rule."

Comment: You can put a plural on very famous family name. "les Tudors" for example. I guess the Simpsons could fit in there :-) http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/accord-du-nom-de-famille