# How do you form plurals of proper nouns in French?

Tags: pluriel, noms-propres

I found a [list](http://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-make-french-nouns-plural/) of rules for forming plurals from regular nouns, which states that last names aren't changed when pluralized (just the article changes).  Does this also apply to proper nouns? (ie How would I say "two Apple Ipods" or "some Toyota Matrixes"?)

If there's no hard and fast rule, is there something that works most of the time?

Comment: This site seems to answer your question: https://blogs.transparent.com/french/how-to-make-french-nouns-plural/ ("Proper nouns do not change in the plural.  Only the article does: les Goldman, les Roi, les Fabre.")

Comment: Additionally: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [the last name pluralization rule](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9048/217) applies to commercial proper nouns as well. From the [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4118), brand names that start with a capital (hence proper nouns) stay singular:

> - Mes enfants raffolent des **Popsicle** lors des chaudes journées d'été.
> - Elle aimerait bien recevoir des **Nike** pour son anniversaire.
> - Luc préfère les **Ford** aux **Chevrolet**.

However, if a brand name is so popular that it has migrated into the common noun category, it is then written with a lowercase and pluralized normally:

> - Tu devrais prendre deux **aspirines** avant de te coucher.